# convert wav to flac with tags

Tags: conversion, flac, wav

long story short:  I need a script to convert wav files to flac, while taking the file name (minus extension) to place in the song title tag of the flac file.

I have about 1200 audio CDs that I decided to archive lossless on a terabyte drive.  Since there was plenty of room, I used k3b to rip them as wav files, thinking that would save a lot of time by skipping the compression step. Well, it did, but I had already ripped quite a few before I caught the error:  when I try to import them into a player like Rhythmbox, they don't have any tags (meta data) so it can't identify and sort them properly.  I've switched to ripping the rest to flac to avoid that problem, but I'd like to fix the error without going back and remounting all of those CDs again.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Install the `flac` command from the package of the same name and run

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.wav' |
while read file # eg stuff/artist/album/title.wav
do      file="$PWD/${file#./}" # make absolute to get more info
        album=${file%/*}    # stuff/artist/album
        artist=${album%/*}  # stuff/artist
        album=${album##*/}  # album
        artist=${artist##*/} # artist
        title=${file##*/}   # title.wav
        title=${title%.wav} # title
        flac -s --best --delete-input-file \
         --tag="TITLE=$title" \
         --tag="ALBUM=$album" \
         --tag="ARTIST=$artist" \
         "$file" # creates .flac removes .wav
done
```

The title is the basename of the file, minus the .wav suffix,
album is the immediate directory above, and artist the
directory above that. The `--delete-input-file` option
removes the .wav. See *Parameter Expansion* in the bash
man page for `${var%pattern}` which removes the glob pattern (i.e. formed with `*` `?` and `[...]`)
at the end of the variable, or at the start (${var#pattern});
the %% and ## versions remove the longest matches.

Comment: Nice. I think you want `${file##*/}` to handle a/b/c.wav

Comment: Thanks!  Would you mind a few refinements?  Is there a way to put the directory name in album title tag?  Or even the directory one up in the artist tag?  Can flac or the script also delete the wav file when it's done?

Comment: I added your refinements. Good luck!

Comment: @meuh, I didn't quite understand your comments.  Anyway, that script apparently did not work.  Rhythmbox sees the title but not artist and album.    I added some substring operators and a few echos to see what I'm getting:

Comment: @meuh, I didn't quite understand your comments.  Anyway, that script apparently did not work.  Rhythmbox sees the title but not artist and album.    I added some substring operators and a few echos to see what I'm getting:<code>
        track=${title:0:2}  # track number
        title=${title:5}    # strip off track number
        echo $track
        echo $title
        ...
         --tag="TRACK=$track"  \

echo $album
echo $artist</code>The $album and $artist echo nothing

Comment: I can't even figure out how to format my comments on here! :-(

Comment: I tried it on the path `stuff/artist/album/title.wav` and it seemed ok. also `metaflac --list` on the resulting flac file had the 3 items, and `metaflac --show-tag=album` seemed ok too.

Comment: @meuh does that mean you ran it from "stuff" or from "stuff/artist/album/"?

Comment: when I ran metaflac --list on a file, I got this:                                 comments: 4
    comment[0]: TITLE=Squealer
    comment[1]: ALBUM=.
    comment[2]: ARTIST=.
    comment[3]: TRACK=09

Comment: I was assuming you would run it from the top of the tree, ie `stuff`, but I suppose you have a legitimate point, you could start lower down. The simple solution is to add a line after the `do` to make the filename absolute: `file="$PWD/${file#./}"`

Comment: @meuh I tried adding [code]file=$PWD/${file#./}[/code] like you said, but it came out the same, i.e. album and artist are blank.

Comment: sorry, I can't think of anything else simple to try. If the absolute `$file` looks ok you could replace the bash ${%} stuff with eg: `album=$(echo "$file" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}')` and `artist=$(echo "$file" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}'`